# How do I prevent a user from accessing a route through the search bar?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I'm working on this Dotnet core MVC/Razor Pages app and it is supposed to prevent users from accessing certain controller routes through the search bar unless they specified it in the register form. How do I achieve this? Does dotnet core MVC have a keyword for this? I'm stuck. Some relevant code for Identity/Account/Register that shows registering is below

```
  [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Choose businesslisting or choice")]
            public string Decision { get; set; }
        }
   public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (Input.Decision == "Business Listing" || Input.Decision == "business listing")
                {

                    if (result.Succeeded)
                    {

                        _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                        var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                        var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                            "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                            pageHandler: null, 
                            values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                            protocol: Request.Scheme);

                        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Change your password",
                       $"Please change your password by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of questions to maybe help clarify your question. What do you mean by search bar? Are your referring to the address bar in the browser? How would they specify it in the register form? i.e is it passed in through a field? What is the field name? To start with you could look at the ASP.Net Core Authorization documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: All you can do is apply authorization to the route to *generally* allow or disallow access for a particular user or role. If you need more advanced determination for authorization, you can use custom policies. However, regardless of how you authorize, you cannot exclude based on something like whether the user typed in a URL directly in the address bar vs. clicking a link, etc. It's all just a request, no matter how it comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the ASP.NET Core Authorization documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You might find claims based authentication useful in this scenario https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Upon creating users you can add specific claims that allow them access to specific controllers/urls.